# Using Event listeners with ngMap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I'm using Allenhwkim's wonderful ngMap in a project. I know that I need to use Maps Javascript v3 API to manipulate the map, which is going well except that I can't get any event listeners, e.g., `$google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function()...`  to work

Specifically, I'm trying to create an onClick event on my markers.
Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/HAcEfWl5LR9SGGqbcXcW?p=preview

Here, I try to use an ng-click attribute on a marker directive. Still, I get nothing. http://plnkr.co/edit/FqwNhqEgDe75il8nU0sC?p=preview

Comment: Can the person that downvoted this question please explain why they did so? I can't learn how to ask better questions unless you explain why this one sucks. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ngMap's specific UI event methods.

Check out this documentation: https://ngmap.github.io/events.html#/event-simple#event-simple

also sample code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="EventSimpleCtrl" class="ng-scope">
      <map zoom="4" center="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-center-changed="centerChanged()">
        <marker position="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-click="click()" title="Click to zoom"></marker> 
      </map>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $scope.click = function(event) {
      map.setZoom(8);
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    }
```

Sample code link: http://plnkr.co/edit/mli6jTMwGE9k35GFPZT9?p=preview

**Edit:**

You can use `google.maps.event.addListener`, but you need to create variables to hold your marker, and add the listeners to the markers.

You can change the code in your script.js to the following:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap']);

  app.controller('mapController', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
    var map;
    $scope.dynMarkers = [];
    $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, evtMap) {
      map = evtMap;
      for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].position[0], markers[i].position[1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:latLng});
        $scope.dynMarkers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            alert("this is marker " + i);
        });

      }
      $scope.markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, $scope.dynMarkers, {});
    });
  });
```

Notice this line `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:latLng});`
You can try in this link: http://plnkr.co/edit/LiblBBvauGnn67xOy96D?p=preview

Comment: Are you saying that I cannot attach a click event without using the marker directive?

Comment: @Jay I didnt use marker directive in my edit answer..... see my preview link: http://plnkr.co/edit/LiblBBvauGnn67xOy96D?p=preview

Comment: Thanks to your edit and your second plunker, I finally see what I did wrong! Thanks a lot, ztan!!

Comment: For anyone else facing this problem, new versions of ng-map require a small change to get instance map. 
$scope.map is deprecated. Use NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {...}) instead to get a map instance.