# ng-map: How can I get the Marker object when I click it?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I am using the pretty cool [ng-map](http://ngmap.github.io/) library for angular, and I want to know how to access the underlying Marker Object referenced by ng-map **marker** directive

So, I have this markup:

```
<div id="map-search" data-tap-disabled="true">
  <map zoom="15" disable-default-u-i="true">
    <marker ng-repeat=" pos in positions" position="{{pos.latitude}}, {{pos.longitude}}" id="{{pos.index}}" on-click="pinClicked()">
    </marker>
  </map>
</div>
```

I haven't found a straight-forward way of accessing the Google Maps **Marker Object** during a *on-click event* in this case; From the controller:

```
  app.controller('MapSearchController', function($scope) {

      $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {
        $scope.map = map;
        //Assume existence of an Array of markers
        $scope.positions = generatePinPositionsArray();
      });

      $scope.pinClicked = function(event, marker) {
        console.log('clicked pin!');
        //HOW CAN I GET THE MARKER OBJECT (The one that was clicked) HERE?
        console.log('the marker ->', marker); //prints undefined
      };
  });
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you sure: `on-click="pinClicked()"` corresponds to `$scope.pinTouched`. You are not calling the same function!

Comment: Oops!, my bad. corrected. it's supposed to be the same method of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an array of markers ! That's (in my opinion) the only way. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28754507/2954267)

**UPDATE**: Does something like this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/m9bhkYFCPVqjTxuX8te6?p=preview) works for you?

The idea is to pass the marker on the event `on-click="pinClicked(this)"`. And then you can catch it later on the controller: `$scope.pinClicked = function(events, marker) {...}`

Comment: Hi @robe007, I wish it was as easy as that, In your example you're choosing the first marker from an array of markers, (therefore, you keep a reference to the Marker object in that variable). In my case, I too have an Array of Markers but any of them can be clicked, not necessarily the first one.

Comment: This is unfortunate, I wanted to avoid having to do what's on the answer you have just linked. Adding event listeners that way is messy. Thank you for your kind replies nonetheless! -Sincerely.

Comment: I update my answer. Hope this could help you. Saludos !

Comment: Great answer! Since you have answered first than @allenhwkim, I will give you the 'Accepted' (even though his answer could be considered to be *better*)

Comment: brilliant! had been struggling for sometime on this.

Answer (score 5):

`this` is the answer to access the market object. It is the exactly the same as Google maps api, nothing is different. Again use `this` inside on-click function.

------ EDIT -----

There are so many examples in testapp directory, those are useful when you find usage of ng-map.

```
$scope.foo = function(event, arg1, arg2) {
  alert('this is at '+ this.getPosition());
  alert(arg1+arg2);
}
```

Example:

https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/testapp/events.html

Comment: Thank you, sir. Could you please illustrate a little bit further how would the controller function would look like? What the signature for the function inside the controller like? (Something like: pinClicked(marker){...}) ?

Comment: Thank you very much, EXACTLY What I needed, sir! Keep up the great work!