# Accessing marker on event listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I'm using `ng-map` for a project and I'm having trouble accessing the marker on on-click event. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445886/ng-map-how-can-i-get-the-marker-object-when-i-click-it) was answered 4 months ago by @allenhwkim that I can access the marker with `this` but when I try that I get `undefined`.

This is how I create my map and markers

```
    <ng-map center="[39.4, 34.744971]" zoom="6"
            street-view-control="false">
        <marker ng-repeat="z in zones"
                position="{{z.alignment.center}}"
                on-click="focusMarker($event)"
        ></marker>
    </ng-map>
```

Event listener sets map's center and zoom to focus on the marker then it pops a info window. In this function, I need the clicked marker so I can access it's attributes

```
    $scope.focusMarker = function(event)
    {
        NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) 
        {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            map.setZoom(12);
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()));
            infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
            infowindow.open(map);
        });
    };
```

Only solution I thought was finding the marker on `event.latLng` coordinates but I'm not able to filter `map.markers` because it's an object not an array as far as I saw.

Comment: I am understanding your question 25% and changing this value inversely would be 52% people won't answer your question.

Comment: Edited my question to make it more understandable but I'm not sure I understood your comment

Comment: I know you didn't understand my comment that's why I wrote it to denote your question is **unclear** . :)

Comment: Is it more clear now?